# Strongswan AWS and overlapping subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, nat, ipsec, strongswan

I have this scenario, I need to connect two sites over a site to site ipsec tunnel. One of the peers (I don't have access to the other side) is an EC2 instance with Strongswan (Ubuntu 16.04). I could connect both sites with this configuration:

```
type=tunnel
authby=secret
left=10.1.0.124 (private ip address assigned by AWS to our EC2 instance)
leftid=18.21.xxx.xxx (public Elastic ip)
leftsubnet=10.153.94.0/24 (this is a requirement from the other side, I don't manage this)
right=45.17.xxx.xxx (public peer ip)
rightsubnet=10.153.105.0/24 (private subnet of peer side)
keyexchange=ikev1
ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
ikelifetime=86400s
esp=aes256-sha1-modp1024!
keylife=3600s
auto=start
rekey=yes
keyingtries=%forever
aggressive=no
dpdaction=restart
dpdtimeout=120
```

The issue is with the remote subnet required by the peer (leftsubnet). We don't have this subnet into our vpcs, and the peer couldn't change this into their cryptomaps. How can I solve this? I need to create some sort of virtual ip (eg 10.153.94.2) inside the EC2 instance, or NAT iptables rules, or both? I can't add a second physical interface with an arbitrary address, and I try to create subinterface (eg ens5:0) without success. The tunnel is up only with the "real" left ip (10.1.0.124) set. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter, where you add your private address. It can also be the loopback device `lo`:

```
ip -4 addr add 10.153.94.1/24 dev lo
```

To add the IP address at boot put:

```
iface lo:0 inet static
    address 10.153.94.1
    netmask 24
```

to `/etc/network/interfaces`. You should be able to do the same with `ens5`.